# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email, smtp

**The server response was: Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client.**

I am using SMTP details of some other server and my code is hosted on some other server. When I am trying to send mail it is giving me error of **SMTP Authentication** as below:

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client.
>
> System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException: Unable to send to all
>   recipients. ---> System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox
>   unavailable. The server response was: Please turn on SMTP
>   Authentication in your mail client.

```
Here is my code:



public void SendIntimation()
            {
                try
                {
                    string strBody = MessageBody();
                    string strToEmail = txtEmail.Text.ToString();
                    string strBcc = "email@gmail.com";
                    MailMessage(strToEmail, strBcc, "Thank you for Register with us", strBody);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex);
                }
            }

        protected string MessageBody()
                {
                    string strBody = "Test 123";
                    return strbody();
                }
     public void MailMessage(string strMailTo, string strMailBcc, string strSubject, string strBody)
            {
        try
                {
                    MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
                    mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("sender@domain.com", "test");
                    mailMsg.To.Add(strMailTo);
                    //mailMsg.CC.Add(strMailCC);
                    mailMsg.Bcc.Add(strMailBcc);
                    mailMsg.Subject = strSubject;
                    mailMsg.Body = strBody;
                    mailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                    mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient mailSmtp = new SmtpClient();
                    mailSmtp.Host = "domain.com";
                    mailSmtp.Port = 25;
                    mailSmtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    mailSmtp.Timeout = 90000;
                    mailSmtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    mailSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    NetworkCredential basicCredential = new 
                NetworkCredential("sender@domain.com", "password",
                "domain.com");                
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex);
                }
    }
```

Comment: `UseDefaultCredentials`  should be `false` and you need `mailSmtp.Credentials = basicCredential;`

Comment: In addition, You need to go to your Gmail account, go to SETTINGS, and enable POP3/SMTP access toyour account

Comment: Hi @AlexK., it was a typo mistake UseDefaultCredentials  is false.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger, it is not for gmail, if I put any other mail id then also the same error comes.

Comment: The error is telling you that the server is not getting authorization for outgoing (smtp) email. Port 25 is inconsistent with SSL.

Comment: Change your port and credential using the basic email function I placed below in my answer - if that works, customize it to your needs

Comment: Obviously - make sure your server uses SSL - if not, change use SSL = false and use port 25;

Answer (score 1):

Try the basic method and work up from there:

```
   using System;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using System.Net.Mail;

   namespace WindowsApplication1
 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("to_address");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
            mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```